# How can we store button text inside session variable in JSP?

Tags: jsp

There exists a JSP Question Answer website. The answer's are shown in the html buttons's.
There are 5 questions, each having 4 answers (so, 4 buttons for each question). I want to store the value of button clicked by user into session so that I can pass all 5 answer's to the next page.

Could you suggest a method for this.

Thanks.

Comment: you can access the value of button in request param

Comment: yes, correct, but I am having multiple buttons. and i need to capture value of one button per question

Comment: How do you populate those buttons? Post the relevant JSP and servlet code.

Comment: i am now using radio buttons for the options. thanks